# How to change value of a particular TD in a row with JQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So if I have table:

```
<table id="someTable">
  <tr><td>Key1</td><td>Value1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Key2</td><td>Value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Key3</td><td>Value3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can get the "index of the row" of value 2 and store the value "Key2" into a variable. Then using that "index of the row containing value2", I change the "first TD"(or if there were three TD's, get the 3rd TD) of that row to something like "changed key"?

Something like "index of tr" and then specifying "index of td" to change... not sure if that is possible with jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the index of the row and cell, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').html('foo');
});
```

You can also pull the current value of the cell using the same selector, but `.html()` rather than `.html(content)`

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yLeWz/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you pass jQuery a `td`, you can get the index of it's containing row (relative to the other rows) with `$(obj).parents("tr").index(); //obj is the td object passed in` 
You can do the same to the table cell:
`$("#yourtable td").eq(index).text("Your Value"); //index is the index you wanna grab`

Answer (score 0):

```
//First, obtain the td that contains 'Value2'
var $tdThatContainsValue2 = $("#someTable tr td").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == "Value 2";
});
//Then, obtain the first td in its row (it's first 'sibling');
$firstCellOfValue2row = $tdThatContainsValue2.siblings("td").eq(0);
alert($firstCellOfValue2row.html());  //Will show "Key 2"
```

Hope this helps